# docker registry per project

Tags: node.js, docker

I want to know, if it is possible to have a docker registry on per project basis similar to the node_modules folder.

So the reason is to avoid collecting garbage and unused images. After I delete a project my system should be clean as before running the container. Same should apply for the mounted folder, they should be relative to the source code.

For example I start a mongodb for node tests and don't want to take care of cleaning the mongo image from my system when I delete the project folder.

I want to have a npm script which pulls the image and put it into a path inside the project itself. Something like an embedded mongodb but based on docker.

On another project I am using a mysql image as db and want to achieve the same behaviour.

The best case would be without installing docker itself. Maybe there is a npm docker wrapper. This should work system independent.

Anyone using docker in a similar way and can point me to some project/code?

Comment: I doubt that is possible, except you can have to package a local registry with every project, which will be big overhead

Comment: All I found until now is just this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/docker-cli-js. Its might be a solution to pull,start and stop the containers.